# Merge multiple chapters into one thesis document

Tags: latex, tex, texstudio

I am fairly new to Latex.
I have written my thesis in Latex. I have 6 chapters and have made individual stand-alone files for each chapter. The main \thesis folder has a total pf 8 folders containing chapters 1 to 6, bibliography and acknowledgments, (\thesis\ChapterOne.. so on) for each chapter with all the necessary figures, tables, etc.

I tried to put the thesis together using main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\begin{document}
\input{\...\thesis\acknowledgements\cacknowledgements.tex}
\input{\...\thesis\ChapterOne\ChapterOne.tex}
\input{\...\thesis\ChapteroTwo\ChapteroTwo.tex}
.
.
\end{document}
```

I am not able to compile the file and get this error

```
Can be used only in preamble. \usepackage
```

How do I get around this?
I also need help with adding the table of contents and list of figures and tables.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the `subfiles` package

Comment: Any `\usepackage` command in any file that is not main.tex? Your _preamble_ is only before `\begin{document}`, so exclusively within main.tex.

Comment: @MattAllegro, yes there are\usepackage files in each of the chapter files. They are standalone files like I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do something similar with the subfiles package and a conditional like the one used here:
http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/language/latex/latex23-Conditioning/ar01s02.html.